# What's the formula of Vector Refraction which Blender implemented?

Tags: procedural, mathematics, vector

The only Vector Refraction formula I could find online is:
\begin{equation}
t = \mu \textbf{i} + \textbf{n}\sqrt{1- \mu^2[1-(\textbf{ni})^2]} - \mu \textbf{n}(\textbf{ni})
\end{equation}
Such that Ratio of Indices of Refraction is: $\mu = \dfrac{n_1}{n_2}$ and Dot Product $\textbf{n}\textbf{i}= n_{\text{x}} i_{\text{x}} + n_{\text{y}}i_{\text{y}}  + n_{\text{z}} i_{\text{z}}$ denotes the dot
(scalar) product of normal vectors $\textbf{n}$ and incident vector $\textbf{i}$.

If this is not the formula that Blender implemented to find its refracted vector, then what is? And why? Because this literally is the only formula I could find and it works really well.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just a suggestion. You might have better luck getting an answer on the Blender Developer Talk forum. https://devtalk.blender.org/

Comment: @curious_1 Thank you for the suggestion. I'm checking it out!